# Samba shares to Azure AD, possible?

Tags: azure, domain, samba

We have centos7 based fileserver with simple samba shares in premises and now the organization (elementary school) want join azure AD (cloud), is it possible to offer our old samba shares to that AD as a service to the domain users without windows servers or costly storage plans?

If it is possible, how? :)

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135666/authenticate-samba-using-azure-ad

Comment: Azure Files is probably what you're looking for. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction

Comment: When you say Azure AD, do you mean Azure AD joined Windows machine or AD synced to AAD? Btw, probably you may want to use Azure File Sync to Azure Files, but would be helpful to understand if you need to control the access using AAD or AD.